# Printing multiple iterated arrays in Bash so they alternate

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I have 2 arrays, where `artists` includes music artist names and `songs` includes song titles. What I want to do is output each in an alternating manner so that I get `array1[1] - array2[1], array1[2] - array2[2]...`, or:

`Chelsea Wolfe - Mer
Pavement - Embassy Row
Black Math Horseman - Torment of the Metals
...`

Here is what I have now, with example arrays provided. The actual arrays are the result of echoed and processed (with grep) curl command substitutions, so I'm not sure if they contain double quotes, but the output I get is same as the example provided here. [Edit: This is incorrect. As I mentioned in a comment to John1024 below, the actual arrays I'm using have newlines after each element.]

I know this is wrong, and I know why (because I'm telling Bash to "print all elements of `artists` then all elements of `songs`"), I just don't know the solution.

```
artists=("Chelsea Wolfe" "Pavement" "Black Math Horseman" "Marriages" "Chelsea Wolfe")
songs=("Mer" "Embassy Row" "Torment of the Metals" "The Liar" "The Waves have Come")

IFS=$'\n'
for ((i=0;i<"${#artists[@]}";++i));
do
printf "%s\n" "${artists[@]} - ${songs[@]}"
done
[Edit: I removed the useless unassigned `OIFS` variable that was here. See my comment to glenn jackman below.]
```

Would it make sense to somehow combine them in the alternating way I want, and then have that array print, or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: A note: you never assign the variable `OIFS`, so you're assigning `IFS` to an empty string at the end of your script (which may matter if this is just a snippet)

Comment: Yes, the script is 100 or so lines, this is just a portion. I think you are right though, I did forget to assign `OIFS`. I've since amended the script to include your suggestion, so `IFS` and `OIFS` have been removed completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's eliminate the `IFS` commands and make some small changes to the `printf` command:

```bash
artists=("Chelsea Wolfe" "Pavement" "Black Math Horseman" "Marriages" "Chelsea Wolfe")
songs=("Mer" "Embassy Row" "Torment of the Metals" "The Liar" "The Waves have Come")

for ((i=0;i<"${#artists[@]}";++i));
do
    printf "%s - %s\n" "${artists[$i]}" "${songs[$i]}"
done
```

This produces the output:

```
Chelsea Wolfe - Mer
Pavement - Embassy Row
Black Math Horseman - Torment of the Metals
Marriages - The Liar
Chelsea Wolfe - The Waves have Come
```

#### Alternate output

We can get the columns to line up by changing the printf line to:

```bash
printf "%-20s - %s\n" "${artists[$i]}" "${songs[$i]}"
```

With that change, the output becomes:

```
Chelsea Wolfe        - Mer
Pavement             - Embassy Row
Black Math Horseman  - Torment of the Metals
Marriages            - The Liar
Chelsea Wolfe        - The Waves have Come
```

#### Handling arrays with trailing newlines

Suppose, as per the comments, that the elements have trailing newlines:

```
artists=($'Chelsea Wolfe\n' $'Pavement\n' $'Black Math Horseman\n' $'Marriages\n' $'Chelsea Wolfe')
songs=($'Mer\n' $'Embassy Row\n' $'Torment of the Metals\n' $'The Liar\n' $'The Waves have Come')
```

We can remove the those newline characters using bash suffix removal:

```
for ((i=0;i<"${#artists[@]}";++i));
do
    printf "%s - %s\n" "${artists[$i]%$'\n'}" "${songs[$i]%$'\n'}"
done
```

The output is still:

```
Chelsea Wolfe - Mer
Pavement - Embassy Row
Black Math Horseman - Torment of the Metals
Marriages - The Liar
Chelsea Wolfe - The Waves have Come
```

Comment: That work for the example arrays given, thank you. It still produces the `artist artist artist - song song song` output for the actual arrays I am using, but I'll figure that out on my own (apparently the elements stored in those arrays are not in the format I thought). I suppose I should learn a language more conducive to this kind of thing (although it's quite a learning experiencing to attempt it using Bash).

Comment: Without knowing your larger project, it is hard to know what language to suggest.  Bash, awk, and python can all be good depending on the circumstances.  As for your mystery arrays, to find out what is actually in a bash array, run `declare -p songs` (replacing `songs` with whatever your array name is).  This will give you complete details on the array's contents.

Comment: It looks like there are newlines in each array, each element is printed on a separate line. Briefly: I want to keep a record of my music listening habits locally, and since I already use last.fm, I thought I would just use their API.  Ideally, I want to export my listening history to .csv to graph the data and spot trends. I know very little Python, but I think it would be the best fit. I could probably do what I want in R, which I am familiar with, it's just not the first thing that comes to mind when I want to process text embedded in API responses. I bet there's a package for it, though!

Comment: I updated the answer with a method for dealing with the trailing newlines.  Separately, if you want CSV format, then you are right: python would be an excellent fit.  Use python's [`csv` package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) (`import csv`).  Bash and awk have only limited ability to handle the potential complexities of CSV format.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with a `paste` and some process substitution:

```
$ paste <(printf "%s\n" "${artists[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${songs[@]}")
Chelsea Wolfe   Mer
Pavement    Embassy Row
Black Math Horseman Torment of the Metals
Marriages   The Liar
Chelsea Wolfe   The Waves have Come
```

That's a bit messy, let's pretty it up with `column`:

```
$ paste <(printf "%s\n" "${artists[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${songs[@]}") | column -t -s $'\t' -o " - "
Chelsea Wolfe       - Mer
Pavement            - Embassy Row
Black Math Horseman - Torment of the Metals
Marriages           - The Liar
Chelsea Wolfe       - The Waves have Come
```

Comment: The first example worked perfectly, nicely formatted, even with the actual arrays I'm using which contain newlines. Using the second example, Bash says the `-o` option is invalid. I don't see it in the man page, either. I Must have an older version.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're struggling is that the shell is an environment from which to call tools, not a tool for manipulating text, and so it's extremely difficult to write shell scripts to manipulate text. The guys who invented shell to call UNIX tools also invented the UNIX tool `awk` for the shell to call to manipulate text so just use it:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=","; OFS=" - "

    split("Chelsea Wolfe,Pavement,Black Math Horseman,Marriages,Chelsea Wolfe",artists)
    split("Mer,Embassy Row,Torment of the Metals,The Liar,The Waves have Come",songs)

    for (i=1;i in artists;i++) {
        print artists[i], songs[i]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
Chelsea Wolfe - Mer
Pavement - Embassy Row
Black Math Horseman - Torment of the Metals
Marriages - The Liar
Chelsea Wolfe - The Waves have Come
```